# WC shipment based on weight + payment method

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I installed a plugin for shipment based on weight but I need also to add for a specific payment method (COD) + x dollars
so [weight-based] + x
how could I do this?
Thanks for the help

Comment: You could hire a skilled developer who will do it for you.

Comment: **[`How To Ask ?`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Comment: I need to acquire this skill now, thanks for the help